# Sharing File Handle between two different proceses

Tags: windows, win32-process

Suppose there are two processes p1 and p2 , p1 opens a handle to a file and shares this handle to p2 through shared memory, will the p2 able to use it?

Comment: no. you need duplicate handle to process, not just pass handle as is.

Comment: [No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle).

Comment: YES, p2 can use the handle in shared memory, IF the handle is created/set by p1 as an inheritable handle via `CreateFile()` or `SetFileInformation()`, and then p2 is created via `CreateProcess()` and instructed to inherit handles from p1. Otherwise, you could just pass the filename to p2 via command-line parameter or IPC and let p2 open its own handle to the file separately.